# Codeception: What is the difference between canSeeRecord() and seeRecord()

Tags: yii2, phpstorm, codeception

I'm using Codeception for unit tests in Yii2 application. Yii2 module has a documented [seeRecord()](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Yii2.html#seeRecord) method. There is also similar `canSeeRecord()` without any online documentation, but with additional info in PHPDoc:

> Conditional Assertion: Test won't be stopped on fail

But what does it actually mean? On test fail PhpStorm shows only first error, so I don't see any difference. Is there any practical difference between these two calls:

```
$this->tester->seeRecord(MyModel::class, ['name' => 'rob006']);
$this->tester->canSeeRecord(MyModel::class, ['name' => 'rob006']);
```

Comment: i dont see any method implemented with the name `canSeeRecord()` in `codeception\Module\Yii2.php`

Comment: It is in `_generated\UnitTesterActions` when you enable `orm` part in Yii2 module. So you can use it as `$this->tester->canSeeRecord()` from unit test class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documented at https://codeception.com/docs/03-AcceptanceTests#Conditional-Assertions

> Usually, as soon as any assertion fails, further assertions of this
>   test will be skipped. Sometimes you don’t want this - maybe you have a
>   long-running test and you want it to run to the end. In this case, you
>   can use conditional assertions. Each `see` method has a corresponding
>   `canSee` method, and `dontSee` has a `cantSee` method:
>
> ```
> $I->canSeeInCurrentUrl('/user/miles');
> $I->canSeeCheckboxIsChecked('#agree');
> $I->cantSeeInField('user[name]', 'Miles');
> ```
>
> Each failed assertion will be shown in the test results, but it won’t stop the test.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that PHPDoc was right - test will continue after failed assertion. But in my case I was confused by PhpStorm integration, which reports only first error.

I created simple test:

```
public function testTest() {
    // products table is empty - these tests always fail
    $this->tester->canSeeRecord(Product::class, ['id' => 1]);
    $this->tester->canSeeRecord(Product::class, ['id' => 2]);
    $this->tester->canSeeRecord(Product::class, ['id' => 3]);
}
```

PhpStorm shows only first error in this test:

[image]

But when you run this tests from console, all three errors are reported:

[image]